# Is it normal to hard code the input of over 80 input fields?

Tags: database-design, php

This is my first time trying to do database work from scratch, mostly for learning sake. So I'm not sure how to organize my database and tables. Basically, I want to start with a web form and put the given data in a few tables. I'm unsure because every tutorial only has like 3 input fields, but my form will probably have well over 50, maybe closer to 100.

So the question is, should I really have to hard code every input to a corresponding table?  For example:

$customer_name = $_POST["customer_name"];

Then INSERT those variables into my db? Do I need to make an array and automate some of this work? What's the standard thing to do for larger tables or multiple tables?

Comment: You could use a PHP framework like Codeigniter which uses Active Record. You can insert into/update the database by passing it an array. On a side note, if your form has 100 pieces of entry, maybe you should consider breaking up your forms into smaller chunks.

Comment: I will certainly have them sectioned off in chucks with accordion headers for the visual side of things. Is that why you say that, or could I have performance problems with that many fields?

Comment: I'm talking more performance wise. Inserting 100 items will take longer than 50. But you should also consider the width of your table, this can have a huge performance hit. If they've got 100, 2000 varchar fields in a single table your query performance will suffer. Best to break these into 1-1 tables.

Comment: Split the input over several pages, and make the fields accept null values while the forms are being filled.

Answer (score 0):

I have two concerns.

- A table with 80 columns may not be normalized.  Once you've normalized the table you may find the screen size shrinks.
- 80 fields on a page seems excessively busy. As you mentioned sectioning the form with accordian headers, you may want to use separate forms for each section.  These sections may help with normalization of the data.

Answer (score 0):

No, that's definitely not normal.

Let's leave the question of whether it's appropriate to have 80 columns in a table aside for a second. (It's probably not, but… yeah, let's move on.) It's still definitely not appropriate to have to hard-code every one of them — with that many fields, it's probably going to make more sense to define them as some sort of array or structure, and process them in a generic fashion, e.g.

```
$fields = ["customer_name", "blah", "blah2", "blah3", ...];

foreach ($fields as $field) {
    $input = $_POST[$field];
    do stuff with $input;
}
```